# What is another use for port 8080/8443 other than a proxy?

Tags: http, proxy, nmap, ports, http-proxy

I see alot of servers with port `8080` open. Most times I am able to connect to the proxy server, but the majority are unable to make requests outside the network, or internally.

What is the purpose of having these ports open on servers if they do not serve as proxies?

I come across over 100 per day. All with the same two ports open `8080` and `8443`. Rarely do they require authentication.

Are there any other uses for these ports that require them to be open other than serving as a proxy?

Comment: 80 and 443 are HTTP and HTTPS ports, 8080 and 8443 indicates those ports are used for similar traffic

Comment: @Ramhound yes, I already said that in my question. I understand both are proxies.

Comment: How are we suppose to know the reason, a specific unnamed server, has these ports opened.  If port 8080 is a proxy then port 8443 is a SSl proxy using logic.

Comment: Again, you're reading the question wrong @Ramhound. I find 100's of these on a daily basis. I am aware of open proxies, jesus I used to abuse them back in the day. If you read the question though I state that addresses outside the network are not accessible (neither are internal), so they're not open proxies. I see them so frequently that there has to be another purpose for them ... which is why I am asking does anyone know of any other reason these ports would be open.

Comment: Please be respectful of people.  I only see a single question, your asking what the purpose of these ports are, you have been told that purpose.

Comment: Please tell me where I have disrespected anyone?

Comment: *Your comments towards me.*

Comment: Again, please tell me where I have disrespected you. I merely stating that you're reading the question completely wrong. You're assuming I don't know what open proxies/closed proxies are even though I've stated in the question that I know the purpose for these ports. Your first comment is reiterating the obvious.

Comment: I feel you are being disrespectful to me, in pretty much, every single one of your comments.

Comment: @Ramhound then I appologize if you feel that way. I will remove the question and resubmit with better wording. It appears I can not remove it because it has answers. I have edited the question.

Comment: Q: "What is another use for port 8080/8443 other than a proxy?" A: *Anything*.  Ports are not force-tied to a service type, so with the 100 of port 8080's you see in a day, there's no reason to suspect they are all hosting the same type of service.  Tons of programs use 8080 and 8443 for their web services by default, to stay out of the way of 'regular' web (80 and 443) servers, but which ports are used by any service is (basically) arbitrarily picked by the authors.

Comment: @BugHunterUK - You wouldn't want to remove it even if you could.  If you remove questions that are not well received, instead of fixing the problem, you will eventually be prevented from submitting new questions.  *So get out of the habit of deleting questions.* I personally don't delete questions, even if they received, 16 downvotes in their lifespan

Comment: @BugHunterUK Because someone wants to run a different service on port 80 and port 8080, or port 443 and port 8443. We cannot answer **why**. You need to ask the owner of the service only **only the owner can know why he chose those ports**.

Comment: @BugHunterUK Like mentioned. 8080 could be anything. But the most common is an alternative to HTTP. That is even it's documented purpose according to the Port Authority Database https://www.grc.com/port_8080.htm. So if you think the purpose for these ports are proxies and you are mad at someone telling you otherwise, especially when you make a question asking what they are for, I think you owe them an apology.

Comment: have you tried finding out which service in the server is using those ports?

Answer (score 5):

Although Google would get these answers quickly, 8080 is officially recognized as HTTP Alternate of 80, essentially the same function. From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers)

> HTTP alternate (http_alt)—commonly used for Web proxy and caching
>   server, or for running a Web server as a non-root user

Port 8443 is not official, but is often used as an alternative to 443 (HTTPS) in a similar fashion, and according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers) is also for

> SW Soft Plesk Control Panel, Apache Tomcat SSL, Promise WebPAM SSL,
>   McAfee ePolicy Orchestrator (ePO)

With Apache Tomcat SSL being the most likely service in this case.

Comment: Ports `80` and `443` are already open so what's the purpose in have these open too? It's evident they're not open proxies, internal and external addresses can not be accessed. Hence why I asked the question.

Comment: @BugHunterUK Because someone wants to run a different service on port 80 and port 8080, or port 443 and port 8443. We cannot answer **why**. You need to ask the owner of the service only **only the owner can know why he chose those ports**.

Answer (score 1):

As you said, the servers you see with port 8080 may be a open proxy server (not necessary, this port may also be used for HTTP server).

The reason why it is open, is to allow users to connect to the internet through its connection. Some users use this kind of service to break security barriers imposed on the place they are connected (public hotspot/university/company internet) or regional barriers (some internet content is filtered by country for eg.

Comment: I have edited my question, this is not the question I asked. I know what those ports are. I am questioning why they are open, yet unable to access addresses outside, or inside, the network.

Comment: While I might not agree this answer is high quality, it certainly does answer your question, which was "What is the purpose of having these ports open on servers?"

Comment: @Ramhound If you read my question I already state that I am aware both are proxies, so what is the purpose in reiterating this as an answer?

Comment: "I understand port 8080 is a proxy server, but what is the use of these proxies?" ... see.

Comment: @BugHunterUK - Like I said.  I don't think this answer should exist, but it certainly does answer the question, you asked though

Comment: @BugHunterUK maybe I didn't got your question, but I tried to explain the reason why these ports may be open - They can be anything, but it is often used to (1) open proxy server, or (2) an HTTP server; 8080 TCP  HTTP alternate (http_alt)—commonly used for Web proxy and caching server, or for running a Web server as a non-root user - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers

Comment: Remembering that you not being able to use those servers as proxy does not mean it is not a proxy. Some missconfigured firewalls may expose a proxy to the internet, but drop the traffic that is not coming from their trusted network. In other words, there are many reasons why you might see an open 8080 port. Most often used to proxy and HTTP, as I said.